How to get Toggle Animate works
When I click on "Show Menu" button, text runs out from the left, that is working as expected.
Then I write function() { $(this).next('#menu').animate({'margin-left': '-50'}) to get the text runs back to left and disappear when "Show Menu" button is clicked again, but somehow it doesn't work!
Thanks for your help!


$(function() {
$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).next('#menu').animate({'margin-left': '25'}).animate({'margin-left': '0'},
  function() {
  $(this).next('#menu').animate({'margin-left': '-50'})
  })
})
})
#menu {
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-left: -50%;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Show Menu</button>
<div id="menu">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>




You can use toggleClass to keep track of the visibility and add a transition to it.


$("button").click(function() {
  $("#menu").toggleClass("visible");
});
#menu {
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-left: -50%;
  transition: margin-left 800ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.27, 1.55);
}

#menu.visible {
  margin-left: 0%;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Show Menu</button>
<div id="menu">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>




Thank you very much for your code, that works well!  Can you let me know why this code function() {$(this).next('#menu').animate({'margin-left': '-50'}) doesn't work for a second click?  I just wonder how to solve this only in .js (not CSS get involved)
